# Find \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{2xy^6 - 2x^5y^2}{(x^4+y^4)^2}

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'd like to show that $$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{2xy^6 - 2x^5y^2}{(x^4+y^4)^2}
$$
doesn't exist.

I've tried approaching along $x=0$, $y=0$, and $y=kx$, and haven't been able to get inconsistent values.

[Background]

The original problem is: given $f:  \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4},\quad if (x,y) \ne (0,0);
& 0\quad , if (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{align}
$$
decide if it's differentiable at $(0,0)$; if not, verify it does not have 
continuous partials in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Clearly $f$ is not differentiable as it's not continuous at $(0,0)$; I'm having trouble showing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ is not continous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: $y=kx$ should work for a suitably chosen $k$.  The numerator is $2x^7(k^6-k^2)$ and the denominator $(1+k^4)^2x^8$, so that if $k^6-k^2\ne 0$, the quotient goes to plus or minus infinity as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Or minus infinity, if you approach from $x<0$ side

Comment: can't believe i didn't see that... thanks!

Comment: when numerator and denominator are homogeneous, try polar coordinates. If that shows a limit that depends on $\theta,$ you are done, no limit.